# Update selection with right click on PrimeFaces DataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

Im using JSF 2.1 with PrimeFaces. I have a `<p:dataTable/>` with selection enabled. Everything working as expected but i need it to change the selection in my ManagedBean when i right-click it !

I use:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":MyComponent"/>
```

and it works. It updates my components and everything but it doesn't change the `selectedEntity` in the bean.

I try with `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@this"/>` but it doesn't work. I think it just set the object to null so... my question is:

What can i do to set the selectedRow in the bean when i right-click a PrimeFaces DataTable ? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `process` attribute. That defines what to process in the form you're sending via ajax request. Don't know how PF does it, but you probably need to send the whole table: `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="table" update=":MyComponent"/>`

Comment: Thanks for answering. PrimeFaces dataTable use " process="@this" " by default. Anyway, i tried including it by myself but it doesn't change the selection as well :/

Comment: Seems to be [related](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24653).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use right-click you must use `<p:contextMenu>` and in your `<p:dataTable>` add `<p:ajax event="contextMenu" update=":MyComponent"/>`

more information from [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml)

Comment: An interesting observation here is that if you put `<p:contextMenu>` before the target `<p:dataTable>`, this won't work.

Comment: @kosgeinsky: As is mentioned in the PF documentation